# Neo4j doesn't start anymore

Tags: neo4j

My Neo4j database wasn't responding anymore, so I had to kill the process and after that it doesn't start anymore. Can someone please help me to fix it? Here is the error log:

```
016-05-16 07:41:05.422+0200 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2016-05-16 07:41:05.423+0200 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3ae47c3d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3ae47c3d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3ae47c3d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:235)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3ae47c3d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:195)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /tmp/sarah/neo4j-community-2.3.3/data/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$1.newGraphDatabase(CommunityNeoServer.java:66)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@2e964f90' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Store and its lock file has been locked by another process: data/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.storeLockException(StoreLocker.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:79)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:44)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        ... 12 more
2016-05-16 07:47:13.337+0200 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2016-05-16 07:47:13.338+0200 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3ae47c3d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3ae47c3d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3ae47c3d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:235
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Store and its lock file has been locked by another process: data/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
```

It looks like you still have some neo4j process running in the background. See if you can find it and then kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error message this morning.  Here is what worked for me. I created a new database folder, pointed the startup screen to the new location -  that start up was successful.  I then shut down this new instance and re-pointed to an existing (failing) db location which then started up as per normal.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the existing Graph and created a new one. This time I made sure I select the correct version of Graph(3.5.0 in my case) that matches with the latest plugin (APOC etc.)library versions and my database started successfully.